# Game Design: Is a plug-in the best solution for this Problem? (Cocoa, Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I've started helping with an open source game (based on Cocoa, Obejctive-C, Xcode).  The existing game engine is already setup to allow the character to run around the world, encounter an enemy, and when combat is begun, a characterObject is called with the enemy unit object that is to be attacked. This characterObject has a default method of attacking the enemy.

I wanted to improve on this design by extending the program to allow others to develop a combatUnit plugin that would handle the combat actions in their own programmed way.  This could open up the community to develop different styles of combat and come up with their own unique play style.

As I began to look into Plug-Ins and examples on how to build, most of the examples kept the plug-in relatively isolated from the internals of the rest of the program.  And any data the plugin required would be passed into the routine(s) themselves.

However, in this case, a combat unit developer might want to have access to numerous external objects in the existing game:  a developer might want to also know of any nearby enemy units to avoid any potential adds in a fight and would have to access several of the existing environment objects to get that data, the character might be in a group and the developer might want access to the group info and each players data to determine if they should heal, etc...  Not knowing what a developer has in mind, it would be unfeasible for me to attempt to predict and pass in all potential info for them to use.

So, my question is:
Is this a good application for a Plug-In?  If so, when developing the plug-in how do I open up the other objects for the plug-in developer to code against?

Is there another approach to solve this problem?  Something else than a "Plug-in" that would be more appropriate for the code to have access to the game's objects?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s a good case for making plug-ins. As an alternative you could compile the new objects directly into the game or use a scripting language interpreter. But with those you’d have to solve the same problems of how to give access to the internals of the game to the new combat unit.

The cleanest way to do this would be to define an interface to the game (either as a protocol or a base class) and pass that to the plug-in. Using this object the plug-in can then query anything it needs.